# Is it possible to use 1 JS file for 2 HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I'm trying to write JS code so that when a button is pushed in the first HTML page, in the second HTML page some content is displayed. I tried to do it in one JS file but it did not work, so I'm asking if maybe I have to use two separate JS files and in that case how do they communicate with each other? I'm using jQuery.

Comment: You're asking if clicking in one page can cause another page to change? Yes, this can be done in a couple of ways, but of course both would be based on the assumption that both pages were open in the first place.

Comment: Is there any relationship between the two pages, like one opened the other, or one is an iframe in the other?

Comment: Without a relationship, this probably needs to go through the server.

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to bear any relationship to the question. The answer to the title is yes -- for instance, there are thousands of HTML files using the same `jquery.js` file.

Comment: If the pages are related, you can use [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate between them.

Comment: We are assuming the page with the button is open and the other one is closed, both of the same website (same project) I Will try with postMessage(), ty @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mean that two HTML pages are of the same website or they are two pages apart.

But if you mean the both are of the same website, I advise you to do the functionally of the page 2 on a div in page 1 and then only change the content dynamically by clicking the button on page 1 by jquery. "append()" function must be very usefull for this.

If the two pages are not related and they are of the same website, you can pass a JSON to the LocalStorage and then use it in page 2 by appending the JSON values between the html tags.

Whatever, if the two pages are so different or are not of the same website, you have to develop a websocket with "socket.io" or just use another "listener" library (like "datatable" for jquery) to show the data dynamically in page 2 in the case data comes from a db (should be the best way).

Please let me know if this is usefull or how can I help more.

Comment: I guess you are hispanic so you can reply form now on in Spanish if you want :). In this case we are assuming both pages are of the same website, the one with the button is open and the other one is closed. I tried to do it with append() but the content is displayed in the same page, not in the closed one. I Will try to do it with JSON, ty!

Comment: Oh man I so sorry if my english gave me away. You can try with the LocalStorage and then open an script tag in the page 2 and use your localStorage values in local variables. However remember you can require HTML pages simultaneously on the same DOM if you are using a server for mount your site and then you can set the getElementeById("wherever you whant to put yout data") on a variable and after you make this: variable.append(whatever you want). Please if it is usefull feel free to accept my answer